# Django order by a field from a related model returns duplicate objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have these two models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class ProductPack(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

And I have a queryset of Product model:

```
products = Product.objects.all()
# <ProductQuerySet [<Product: first product>]>
```

I want to order products queryset by "productpack__price". So I tried to do this by this code:

```
qs = products.order_by("productpack__price")
```

This works partly correctly. But there is one problem. For each object in the products, This code returns objects to the count of foreignkey that they have with ProductPack.
Like this:

```
qs
<ProductQuerySet [<Product: first product>, <Product: first product>, <Product: first product>]>
```

How to fix this problem. Have you any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that the same `Product` instance isn't associated with multiple `ProductPack` instances? Because it seems that it is possible because `Product` and `ProdcutPack` have one-to-many relationships, with different prices.

Comment: @gutsytechster Yes, it is. the "first product" instance has three ProductPack instances. That's why it returns the "first product" three times. But I want to it only returns one "first product"

Comment: try `products.order_by("productpack__price").distinct()`

Comment: This behaviour is described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#order-by). Would it work for you to sort `Product` based on the minimum or maximum  price in `ProductPack`?

Answer (score 5):

When you order by `productpacks`, If a `product` is related to multiple `productpacks`, it is returned in the `queryset` once for each `productpack`.

This can be your solution:

```
from django.db.models import Max  


products = Product.objects.annotate(
    price=Max("productpack__price")
).order_by("price")
```

Comment: Wow! this works exactly correctly. That's what I wanted. Thank you very much :)))